# Access child elements inside the DIV - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors, filter

I am trying to find out a way to make its rows clickable. So when I click, it would either output an id or alert something to say it is clickable.

I tried to use jQuery's selectors to access the div name and table rows which are child elements of that div.

So I am trying to access the tr's inside the div "GridLoad", and I am using the jQuery selector to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $('#gridLoad tbody>tr'), but <div id="GridLoad", gridLoad != GridLoad
2. Where is `<table>` ?

Comment: Sorry, I mean where is `<table>`? It's not a valid table

Comment: well I am using a plugin called flexigrid. And this for some reason isn't creating the table tag. :(

Comment: It's not working cause it's not a valid code. You should change `<div id="GridLoad">` to `<table id="GridLoad">`

Answer (score 0):

try $("#gridLoad tr") to get all of the rows under gridload

Comment: it isn't working either!! if I do a $("GridLoad tr").each(function(){alert(this.id);}); I do not get anything :(